# Equivalent of python time.time()-started in golang

Tags: go

In python I can see how many seconds have elapsed during a specific process like,

```
started = time.time()
doProcess()
print(time.time()-started)
```

Whats the equivelent in golang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> [func Since](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since)
>
> ```
> func Since(t Time) Duration
> ```
>
> Since returns the time elapsed since t. It is shorthand for
>   time.Now().Sub(t).

Your Python example in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    started := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(started))
}
```

Output:

```
1s
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    started := time.Now()
    doProcess()
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(started).Seconds())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    begin := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    end := time.Now()

    duration := end.Sub(begin)

    fmt.Println(duration)

}
```